# Ruby: How do I create a stack out of user input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, input, split

Total ruby-baby here, I'm trying to get a hang of it using [this](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/ruby-beginner-en-mzrZ6) Codecademy Tutorial.
Trying to understand it better I'm giving the extra questions a spin and getting stuck while trying, but I don't understand why.

So – The program at hand is very simple: It replaces a single user-defined word within an input with the word REDACTED.
Now: I want to expand the list of redacted words to as many as the user likes, not just one.

Here's my attempt:

```
puts "Please enter your text here: "
text = gets.chomp
puts "Which words would you like to redact? "
redact = gets.chomp

words = text.split(" ")
censorlist = redact.split(" ") 

=begin 
How do I build an array out of this .split to access all the words separately in my if-condition?
=end

words.each do |word|
  if word != censorlist
    print word + " "
  else 
    print "REDACTED " 
end   
end
```

Sorry if this is too basic to ask around here, but I've been spinning this a while and all the answers i found elsewhere don't make sense to me. i just don't know how to access the array I made with .split.
Thank you!

-N.

Comment: I would do this `print words.map {|word| censorlist.include?(word) ? "REDACTED" : word}.join(" ")`. This will create an Array where words in the `censorlist` are replaced with "REDACTED" and then it will join them as a `String` and print the `String`. You have already built your Arrays using `split`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# ask the user for the text to process
puts "Please enter your text here: "
text = gets.chomp

# ask for words to redact. `split()` will split into words by default
puts "Which words would you like to redact? "
redact = gets.chomp.split

redact.each do |word|
  # instead of printing each word, we CHANGE the text supplied
  text.gsub!(word, 'REDACTED')
end
puts text
```

For more Information see [String#split](http://devdocs.io/ruby/string#method-i-split) and [String#gsub!](http://devdocs.io/ruby/string#method-i-gsub-21)

**Update**: as @engineersmnky pointed out, there's an ever easier method:

```
puts "Please enter your text here: "
text = gets.chomp
puts "Which words would you like to redact? "
redact = gets.chomp

# create a Regular Expression matching all words to redact
regex = /#{redact.gsub(' ', '|')}/
puts text.gsub(regex, 'REDACTED')
```

Comment: why not do it this way to avoid iteration `puts text.gsub(/#{redact.join('|')}/i,'REDACTED')`. This also allows for case insensitivity which is a plus when redacting.

Comment: Thanks everyone! That's super helpful! I'll have to look into all the suggestions in detail and try to understand what they do, so it might take a while!